# How to predefine values of system variables?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to predefine system variables like `sys.programGroupName` in the same way like predefine customized installer variables? We need to predefine values for system variables to ensure they are set for other actions/components. Let's say we can switch between a standard installation type and a customized one. For the standard installation the program-group-screen will not be shown and the *Create program group*-action should create the entries with the *"default"* values. The only way I tried successfully is to overwrite the system variable by calling the *Set Variable*-action.

Comment: we are using install4j version 6.0.4

Comment: You could use the API, context.setVariable()